Is there a name for the problem of finding unique subsets of a set of sets.
Consider a set of possible attributes $A$. I have a collection of objects $C = \{c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n\}$, and each object is associated with a subset of attributes from $A$. Is there a name for the problem of finding what sets of subsets (i.e., attributes) are unique for each object?
For example, if $c_1$ has attributes $a_1,a_3,a_7$ and $c_2$ has attributes $a_1, a_2$, then $a_3$ and $a_1 \land a_3$ are unique to $c_1$. Further, $a_2$ and $a_1 \land a_2$ are unique to $c_2$. (There are other unique subsets as well)
This can easily be done brute force by checking all possible subsets of attributes for $c_1$ etc... against the attributes of $c_2,c_3,\cdots,c_n$, but this is extremely expensive computationally.
I think this problem could be framed more simply, but my question is if there is a name for this problem and if it is a known problem?
While I described this problem in the context of sets, this can also be described as a graph theory problem where we have a bipartite graph where $A$ is one part and $C$ is another part, and the connections describe the attributes associated with the nodes.

This sounds a little like Boolean satisfiability.

@K.Jiang Hmm. I could see some similarity with boolean satisfiability. Thanks for the comment!
